# NuGet DLLs Referenced But Not Added to VS Project

Tags: nuget

Myself and several colleagues have seen the same issue.
For example, if I add a nuget package, i.e. Serilog.3.0.1 to a project, the xml and dll files are present in each of the lib folders i.e. packages\Serilog.3.0.1\lib\net471, but whilst the xml files have, the dlls haven't been included in the project for source control (though the dlls are referenced and included in the bin folder). If I don't spot this, check my changes in, when another colleague picks up the latest source for the project, the code fails as the dependencies aren't in the downloaded source. I have to add them manually for each framework folder.
It doesn't happen with every nuget package, but it does mean I have to check when adding/updating a package that the dlls get added.